# width: calc(100%-40px)

Tags: css3, html5

Мне нужно в один рядок, разместить картинки 20*20 слева и справа, и на оставшейся место, блок на 100%.

Картинка-блок-Картинка.
Как это сделать?
Пробовал через calc, не выходит.

Comment: Может вы в calc просто пробелы между знаками забыли прописать?

Answer (score 2):

**flex**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

container {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
</container>
```

**grid**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

div {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
</container>
```

**float**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

container > * {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
}

container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

div {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="img">
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через flex, указав жадность центральному блоку. Можно через гриды:

```css
.string {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px minmax(20rem, 1fr) 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "left content right"; 
}

.string__img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.string__img--left {
  grid-area: left;  
}

.string__content {
  grid-area: content;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;

}

.string__img--right {
  grid-area: right;  
}
```

```html
<div class="string">
  <img class="string__img string__img--left" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/231404/7723056e-1a65-4325-b324-71a46289ef78/s1200">
  
  <div class="string__content">
    Какой-то контент на 100%
  </div>
  
  <img class="string__img string__img--right" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/231404/7723056e-1a65-4325-b324-71a46289ef78/s1200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

calc странный, надо пробелы возле оператора: calc(100% - 40px), иначе он не будет работать